# cleanup with React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Okay, so I generally understand the error I'm getting.

"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

I know I need to do something along the lines of adding a mounted component in the useEffect functions. I actually am not too sure how to implement it, exactly, with what I'm doing.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id)
        
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (shippingCountry) fetchSubdivisions(shippingCountry);
    }, [shippingCountry]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (shippingSubdivision) fetchShippingOptions(checkoutToken.id, shippingCountry, shippingSubdivision);
    }, [shippingSubdivision]);
```

I have done some research, and this appears to be the form I need to follow, but it's not working for me.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true;

  fetchItems().then((newItems) => {
    if (mounted) {
      setItems(newItems);
    }
  });

  return () => {
    mounted = false;
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: What is the use of `mounted` since the function in the `useEffect` will run only once when mounted the function component.

Comment: `setItems(newItems)` will not work since you are [using hook inside an if statement](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: @ShivamJha that is about hooks. setItems can be called inside if statements.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the last form?

Comment: I recommend look into the example mentioned in the document https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks   Codesandbox link to the example https://codesandbox.io/embed/jvvkoo8pq3?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @AbhishekGowda28 Okay. I better see what I need to do. Thank you. This helped a lot!